# Returning a long in a method that uses System.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: java, time, casting, long-integer

I'm writing a method to compute the running time for an algorithm.  The algorithm is run a specified number of trials and then I compute the running time using System.currentTimeMillis().  However whenever I call the method the value always ends up being zero.  Any direction towards fixing this problem is appreciated.

```
public long runTime(algorithm alg, int[] array, int trials)
{

    long initialTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for(int i = 0; i < trials; i++)
    {
        alg.runAlgorithm(array); 
    }

    return ((System.currentTimeMillis() - initialTime) / (long) trials);
}
```

Comment: It sounds like `runAlgorithm` probably takes less than 1ms to run, on average. Without knowing more about it, it's impossible to say much more...

Comment: Try `System.getNanos()` instead and see if you get anything. That might only use millisecond precision too though, so it might not help.

Comment: Using a `float` or `double` instead might help too, since you'd keep the fraction part.

Comment: @Keppil Even if the has mill-second resolution, the numbers will be 1000000 times bigger so you are less likely to get zero after a division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`((System.currentTimeMillis() - initialTime) / (long) trials);`

It seems the Algorithm is taking less than a `1 ms` to complete its loop, and so you need to break it even to smaller unit...  Using `nanoTime()` may do the work for u...

**Eg:**

```
public long runTime(algorithm alg, int[] array, int trials)
{

    long initialTime = System.nanoTime();

    for(int i = 0; i < trials; i++)
    {
        alg.runAlgorithm(array); 
    }

    return ((System.nanoTime() - initialTime) / (long) trials);
}
```

Comment: It's actually `System.nanoTime()`

Comment: @Brian thank you very much for pointing out the typo.......... I corrected it..thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

If your return value is less then one. Use return type `double`. In your example, you should use `double` instance of `long`.